# Where is the implementation of pixman_region32_init()?

Tags: pixman

lib: http://www.pixman.org/

repository: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/pixman/tree/

void pixman_region32_init (pixman_region32_t *region);

I can not find an implementation of that function..

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It's found in pixman/pixman.h (pixman-0.34.0)

```
ypedef struct pixman_region32_data     pixman_region32_data_t;
typedef struct pixman_box32             pixman_box32_t;
typedef struct pixman_rectangle32       pixman_rectangle32_t;
typedef struct pixman_region32          pixman_region32_t;

struct pixman_region32_data {
    long                size;
    long                numRects;
/*  pixman_box32_t      rects[size];   in memory but not explicitly declared */
};

struct pixman_rectangle32
{
    int32_t x, y;
    uint32_t width, height;
};

struct pixman_box32
{
    int32_t x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

struct pixman_region32
{
    pixman_box32_t          extents;
    pixman_region32_data_t  *data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in `pixman-region32.c`. You don't see it because those functions are generated by the `PREFIX` macro and then the code in `pixman-region.c` is used. See here:

```
typedef pixman_box32_t      box_type_t;
typedef pixman_region32_data_t  region_data_type_t;
typedef pixman_region32_t   region_type_t;
typedef int64_t                 overflow_int_t;

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} point_type_t;

#define PREFIX(x) pixman_region32##x

#define PIXMAN_REGION_MAX INT32_MAX
#define PIXMAN_REGION_MIN INT32_MIN

#include "pixman-region.c"
```

It first sets the `PREFIX` macro to `pixman_region32` and then imports the code from `pixman-region.c`.